# Как с помощью bot.send_my_commands() установить команды для конкретного пользователя. Aiogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram, бот, python-telegram-bot

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, что при установке команд для пользователя они устанавливаются для всех пользователей глобально. Возможно ли сделать так, чтобы установить конкретные команды для конкретных пользователей?

```
storage = MemoryStorage()
bot = Bot(token=BOT_TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=storage)
db = Database()

commands_1 = [
    types.BotCommand("start", "Начать"),
    types.BotCommand("help", "Помощь"),
]

commands_2 = [
    types.BotCommand("my_id", "Мой айди"),
    types.BotCommand("card", "Карта"),
]

async def set_commands(commands):
    await bot.set_my_commands(commands)


@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'], state=[None, '*'])
async def start(message: types.Message):
    user_id = message.from_user.id
    chat_id = message.chat.id


    keyboard = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
    keyboard.add(InlineKeyboardButton("Установить команды №1", callback_data="11"),
                 InlineKeyboardButton("Устанвоить команды №2", callback_data="22"))
    
    await bot.send_message(chat_id, "Выберите действие:", reply_markup=keyboard)

    


@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: c.data == '11', state=[None, '*'])
async def create_cmd1(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery):
    user_id = callback_query.from_user.id

    await bot.send_message(user_id, "команды изменены 1")

    await set_commands(commands_1)


@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: c.data == '22', state=[None, '*'])
async def create_cmd2(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery):
    user_id = callback_query.from_user.id

    await bot.send_message(user_id, "команды изменены 2")
    await set_commands(commands_2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Занести id нужного пользователя в базу или config и проверять его с id пользователя который пишет.

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'], state=[None, '*'])
async def start(message: types.Message):
    user_id = message.from_user.id
    chat_id = message.chat.id

    if user_id == 'id вашего пользователя':
        keyboard = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
        keyboard.add(InlineKeyboardButton("Установить команды №1", callback_data="11"),
                 InlineKeyboardButton("Установить команды №2", callback_data="22"))
    
        await bot.send_message(chat_id, "Выберите действие:", reply_markup=keyboard)
    else:
        await bot.send_message(chat_id, "Вы не админ")
```

Answer (score 0):

В telegram api **нельзя** использовать настройку команд под каждого юзера. Выход из ситуации, сделать для нужного юзера его собственные кнопки или сделать команду /commands и выводить список команд доступные для нужного пользователя.

Также советую обратить ваше внимание на библиотеку aiogram_dialog если хотите просто и удобно строить диалоги с пользователями.